# Heading within a div, within a section

Tags: html

Since the div element in html5 has no special semantic meaning, and can be used for styling purposes, is an arrangement like this OK?

```
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Some title</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Other elements such as images, a list and a few paragraphs in here -->
  </div>
</section>
```

The h2 is the heading for the section. I use the div simply as a wrapper, so I can float the header and opening paragraph to the left. The other content will be grouped in the second div, that I will float to the right.

My question is - is this method of separation OK, as I don't want the h2 (being wrapped in the div)to lose its semantic connection with the section.

Answer (score 1):

In your example above, you can simply style the `section` element if your `section` has semantic meaning. The spec. only says that you should use a `div` if the sole purpose of it is for styling.

I've written a bit more about this here: [HTML5: Section or Article?](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/04/html5/html5-section-or-article)

Comment: So the h2 will not lose its semantic connection with the section if I wrap it in a div? I have edited my post to make more sense of what I want o accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: No, it won't lose its semantic meaning if you wrap it in a `DIV`, since `DIV` has no meaning.